# Interesting result on Euclidean distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ be independently distributed $d$ variate normal random variables.Let $D_i$ be the Euclidean distance between $X_i$ and a fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$.(i.e.$||{X_i-x_0}||$) Prove that for any $\epsilon >0$, $ P(\min_{1 \le i \le n} D_i > \epsilon)$ goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

See that $P(\min_{1 \le i \le n} D_i > \epsilon)=P(D_i > \epsilon)^n$.
Now, by Markov's inequality,$P(D_i>\epsilon) \le \frac{E(D_i)}{\epsilon}$
But I cannot give a bound to $E(D_i)$.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to. Let $\phi$ denote the $d$-dimensional Gaussian density, and let $B(x_0, \epsilon)$ be the Euclidian ball around $x_0$ of radius $\epsilon$. Note that $\{D_i < \epsilon\}$ is the event that the gaussian $X_i$ will land in this Euclidian ball, so if we can show that this event has positive probability for any given $x_0, \epsilon$ pair, we will be done, since then in the limit, we will be exponentiating a number strictly less than 1 by a quantity that is growing larger and larger.

In particular, we have that:

$P(D_i < \epsilon)= \int_{B(x_0, \epsilon)} \phi(x) dx \geq |B(x_0, \epsilon)| \inf_{x \in B(x_0, \epsilon)} \phi(x)$ , and we know that by rotational symmetry and monotonicity of Gaussian, this infimum is $\phi(x_0 + \epsilon \frac{x_0}{||x_0||})$. (To see that this is indeed a lower bound, note that $B(x_0, \epsilon) \subset B(0, \epsilon + ||x_0||) $.

You have just shown that $P(D_i < \epsilon) > \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$, and thus you have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(D_i < \epsilon)^n \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-\delta)^n = 0$.

Comment: What is $B(x_0,\epsilon)$? Also, can you make the notations a bit simpler?

Comment: I just added an edit to explain the notation and the overall gist of the proof; let me know if any notation is unclear.

Comment: "we know that by rotational symmetry and monotonicity of Gaussian, this infimum is $\phi((1+\epsilon)x_0)$."I don't get this part

Comment: That is perhaps the most tricky part of this argument (and is not that important; so long as you can establish a lower bound you are OK); note that Gaussians decay as you get farther away from the center, and they are rotationally symmetric, so the farthest you can get from the center in that circle is by adding an epsilon more in the direction of $x_0$ (though I just realized a typo there; let me fix it and hope that clears it more); basically, your circle is going to be within a radius of $||x_0|| + \epsilon$ by triangle inequality, and thus the density is going to be as large there

Comment: And another thing, you need the $0<\delta<2$ otherwise $(1-\delta)^n$ wont go to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity , how will you ensure that?

Comment: I can assure you that $\delta < 1$ since this argument gives a lower bound on a probability.

Comment: You have taken $\delta=\phi((1+\epsilon)x_0)|B(x_0,\epsilon)|$ right?,then is it immediate that $\delta<1$ from here?

Comment: Yeah, that is what $\delta$ is. I mean that is a lower bound on $P(D_i > \epsilon)$ so yes it is.